# How to compare thickness?

Tags: c#, uwp

i want to compare `thickness`, by checking if
`Thickness` A equals `thickness` B,

And.. it dont work. Always false, why?

ps.

Why `new Thickness(2.1) returns 2.09923289[..]` not `2.1`
and `new Thickness(2.0)` returns clear `2.0`?

[image: thickness]

Comment: likely those are double values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double values are not safe to compare, because of how double are stored in memory. I would advise you to use something like `if(Math.Abs(Thickness - new Thickness(2.1)) < TOLERANCE)`. 
You can do a quick test and try to check something like:

```
var passed = false;
if(0.2 + 0.1 == 0.3)
    passed = true;
```

And you'll see that it is `false`

Comment: `if (Math.Abs(lessonGrid.BorderThickness.Bottom - 2.1) < 0.01)`

now works. Thanks a lot, for answer

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, you can accept this answer.

Comment: yep, waiting for it. I have to wait some time before accepting

Answer (score 4):

The values for the left, top, right and bottom of a Thickness are double values.

As such, you have to use Math.Abs to compare them against a tolerance value.

These are the helper methods I've got in my WinUX library which will do the job for you:

```
public static readonly double Epsilon = 2.2204460492503131E-16;

public static bool AreClose(Thickness value1, Thickness value2)
{
    return AreClose(value1.Left, value2.Left) && AreClose(value1.Top, value2.Top) && AreClose(value1.Right, value2.Right) && AreClose(value1.Bottom, value2.Bottom);
}

public static bool AreClose(double value1, double value2)
{
    if (Math.Abs(value1 - value2) < 0.00005)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var a = (Math.Abs(value1) + Math.Abs(value2) + 10.0) * Epsilon;
    var b = value1 - value2;
    return (-a < b) && (a > b);
}
```

You'd then use it in your scenario like this:

```
if (AreClose(new Thickness(2.1), lessonGrid.BorderThickness))
{
    // Code-here
}
```

Original source: https://github.com/jamesmcroft/WinUX-UWP-Toolkit/blob/develop/WinUX/WinUX.Common/Maths/MathHelper.cs

Comment: Thanks for it. I will use it in future :)